# Bind data from column in DataGridView control to a .NET Chart control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, mschart

I have an existing `DataGridView` that is filled with data.  I have a column in the `DataGridView` called "SignalStrength" and I wish to plot that data on a `Chart` control.

I figure the easiest way to do this is simply to bind the data but I cannot figure out the correct syntax.  I want to do something like this:

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindY(DataGridView1, "SignalStrength");
```

This does not compile because I'm not passing the correct type to the `DataBindY` function.  It wants an `IEnumerable` type.  What is the correct way to do this?  I'd hate to have to iterate over my entire `DataGridView` to add the points.

Comment: Does `DataGridView1.Rows` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindY((DataView)DataGridView1.DataSource, "SignalStength");
```